# How to perform multiple asynchronous actions in Ionic 3 and dismiss a loader after everything is done?

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ionic3, fork-join

I developing an Ionic 3 application which has the option to cache a list of articles content on demand. I am using `Storage` which uses promises for its operations.

My code is the following:

**article-service.ts**

```
getArticleFullData(articleId: number) {
    let appSettings = this.appSettingsService.getSettings();
    let params = this.utilsService.serializeQueryParams(appSettings);
    let url = `${this.apiBasePath}Article/GetArticleFullData?articleId=${articleId}&${params}`;
    this.loggingService.logInfo("Getting article full data from url " + url); 
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

**article-cache-service.ts**

```
// saves a single article to the cache
private saveToCache(articleId: number): Observable<any> {

    let key = articleId;
    let obs = this.articleService.getArticleFullData(key);
    obs.subscribe(data => {
        this.storage.set(this.GetArticleFullKey(key), data as ArticleFullData);
    },
        err => {
            this.loggingService.logError("Failed to cache data for article: " + key);
        }
    );

    return obs;
}

// tries to cache a list of article in the cache
// avoids overwriting the data, if exists
public saveArticleDataToCache(articles: ArticleBriefData[]): Observable<{}[]> {

    var obsArray = [];
    for (let article of articles) {
        let key = this.GetArticleFullKey(article.ArticleId);
        this.storage.get(key)
            .then(data => {
                console.log("Storage data for article " + key, data);

                if (!data) {
                    obsArray.push(this.saveToCache(article.ArticleId));
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.loggingService.logError("Failed to check storage for key " + key, err);
            });
    }

    var ret = Observable.forkJoin(obsArray);
    return ret;
}
```

**code containing loader**

```
    this.loadingCtrl.create({ content: "Caching data. Please wait..." });
    this.loadingCtrl.present();

    var all = this.articleCacheService.saveArticleDataToCache(this.articles);
    var subscr = all
        .toPromise()
        .then(data => {
            console.log("All data: ", data);
            this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
            this.loggingService.logInfo("Successfully cached articles ");
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
          this.loggingService.logError("Failed to cache data: ", JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    );
```

The caching process executes correctly, but `then` code is executed immediately (`data` is `undefined`)

I have also tried the `subscribe` approach, but the code within `subscribe` does not seem to be executed (the caching is properly executed, though):

```
    var all = this.articleCacheService.saveArticleDataToCache(this.articles);
    var subscr = all
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("All data: ", data);

            this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
            this.loggingService.logInfo("Successfully cached articles ");
        },
        err => {
          this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
          this.loggingService.logError("Failed to cache data: ", JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    );
```

I am clearly not working properly with `Observable`s here.

**Question:** How to perform multiple asynchronous actions in Ionic 3 and dismiss a loader after everything is done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it using `forkjoin`.

***Note:*** I have extracted code from my app.So change it according to your use case.If you're using `RXJS 5.5.2` then change the `imports` according to latest [**changes here**](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/lettable-operators.md)

```
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'

let myTopicApi = this.getMytopic();
let myarticlApi = this.getMyArticles();
let myPicksAPi = this.getMyPicks();
Observable.forkJoin([myTopicApi, myarticlApi, myPicksAPi])
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.arrangeMytopics(res[0]);
    this.arrangeMyArticles(res[1]);
    this.arrangeMyPicks(res[2]);
    if (loading) { loading.dismiss(); loading = null; }//here you can dismiss your loader
  },
  error => { if (loading) { loading.dismiss(); loading = null; }//here you can dismiss your loader },
  () => { });

getMytopic() {
    return this.topicSer.getMyTopics().map((res: any) => res.json()).map((res: any) => res = res.categories)
      .catch((err: any) => {  })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I am using `rxjs 5.4.0`. My code is already using `forkJoin`, but it does not work as expected. It might be related to what `getArticleFullData` is doing, but I cannot figure out what is wrong (I have added the code for that function as well).

Comment: Try `let` instead of `var` and see that.

Comment: And also it seems you didn't use `forkjoin` properly. I have updated my post. Hope you can get the better idea of how to use `forkjoin`.

Comment: I realized what I have done wrong. `obsArray` which I am using to `forkJoin` is constructed in the `then` of `this.storage.get(key)`. I have simplified the code to have 'saveToCache' (which returns an `Observable`) pushed in the array and it works fine. However, I am losing the check for existence in cache (I cannot understand why the storage does not also allows for sync methods), but this is an issue for another question, if I cannot figure out how to solve it.

Comment: Yes, The problem there is you tried to use both `observable` and `promise` in the mix.But you cannot use like that. You must either convert `observable` to `promise` or `promise` to `observable`.Then that problem also will be vanished.

Answer (score 1):

`Sampath`'s answer helped me find the issue. What I doing wrong is the way I was constructed the `Observable` array (that it is used in `forkJoin`): pushing in the list within `then` function of the `Promise` returned by storage get.

My code after fixing this and that also includes check for item existence (to avoid HTTP call and resetting storage data):

**article-service.ts**

```
getArticleFullData(articleId: number) {
    let appSettings = this.appSettingsService.getSettings();
    let params = this.utilsService.serializeQueryParams(appSettings);
    let url = `${this.apiBasePath}Article/GetArticleFullData?articleId=${articleId}&${params}`;
    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
```

**article-cache-service.ts**

I am using `flatMap` to chain `Observable` obtained from checking if storage has already the key and the actual fetch. If data exists, I return an empty `Observable` to actually cancel the process.

```
private saveToCache(articleId: number): Observable<any> {

    let key = this.GetArticleFullKey(articleId);

    let storageObs = Observable.fromPromise(this.storage.get(key));
    let getArticleObs = this.articleService.getArticleFullData(articleId);

    let obs = storageObs.flatMap(data => {
        if (!data)
            return getArticleObs;
        else
            return Observable.of(null);
    });

    obs.subscribe(data => {

        if (data)
          this.storage.set(key, data as ArticleFullData);
    },
        err => {
            this.loggingService.logError("Failed to cache data for article: " + articleId);
        }
    );

    return obs;
}

public saveArticleDataToCache(articles: ArticleBriefData[]): Observable<{}[]> {

    let obsArray = [];
    for (let article of articles) {

        let obs = this.saveToCache(article.ArticleId);
        obsArray.push(obs);
    }

    let ret = Observable.forkJoin(obsArray);
    return ret;
}
```

**actual subscription**

```
onCacheRefresh() {
    // articles are not loaded for some reason
    if (!this.articles)
        return;

    this.loadingCtrl.create({ content: "Caching data. Please wait..." });
    this.loadingCtrl.present();

    let all = this.articleCacheService.saveArticleDataToCache(this.articles);
    let subscr = all
        .subscribe(data => {
            console.log("All data: ", data);

            this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
            this.loggingService.logInfo("Successfully cached articles ");
        },
        err => {
          this.loadingCtrl.dismiss();
          this.loggingService.logError("Failed to cache data: ", JSON.stringify(err));
        }
    );
}
```